# Two Identical Tables Yields Different DP results

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was solving a Hackerrank problem that is just a plain implementation of Longest Common Subsequence

```py
tbl = [[0]*(len(s2)+1)] * (len(s1)+1)

# iterate the two strings and update the [i][j] location accordingly
for i in range(len(s1)+1):
    for j in range(len(s2)+1):
        if i == 0 or j == 0: continue # outer row/col indices
        elif s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
            tbl[i][j] = tbl[i-1][j-1] + 1
        else:
            tbl[i][j] = max(tbl[i-1][j], tbl[i][j-1])
            
return tbl[len(s1)][len(s2)]
```

This kept giving me the wrong answers, even though I know I was implementing the algorithm correctly.

On a whim, I then decided to try initializing my table differently. I found the following 2D array initialization:

`[[0]*(len(s2)+1) for i in range(len(s1)+1)]`

The only difference is instead of multiplying the outer brackets by `len(s)+1`, I do the row expansion via a `for` loop.

Pressing submit, and voila, it accepts the answer.

Curious, I tossed the two `tbl` initializations in the python console.

```py
>>> x = [[0]*(len(s2)+1)] * (len(s1)+1)
>>> y = [[0]*(len(s2)+1) for i in range(len(s1)+1)]
>>> x == y
True
```

This is surely strange behavior. Even printing the table contents to the terminal proves identical structure.

```py
>>> for row in x:
...     print(row)
... 
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> for row in y:
...     print(row)
... 
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>>
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what would be causing this disparity in output? Thinking this maybe had to do with how it was compiling, I tested  the function locally with the HR given test case inputs `s1 = SHINCHAN; s2 = NOHARAAA`, and yielded an incorrect LCS of 6 with my (broken) table init and the correct LCS of 3 with the one I found online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the classic Python blunders.  You cannot initialize a 2D array using the `*` operator, like `x = [[0]*5]*5`.  The REASON is that this gives you a list that contains 5 references to the SAME `[0,0,0,0,0]` list,  They aren't 5 independent lists.  If you change `x[0][3]`, you will also change `x[1][3]` and `x[2][3]`.  Try setting `x[2][2] = 9` and `y[2][2] = 9` and notice the difference.

```
>>> x[2][2] = 9
>>> y[2][2] = 9
>>> for row in x:
...     print(row)
...
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> for row in y:
...     print(row)
...
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Ah I see, it's an array of list references. Strange that the == operator would consider them equal then. Even throwing it in assert() doesn't highlight their structural difference

Comment: By default, `==` looks at the contents.  The contents are the same.